# Python restart script in another cmd's window

Tags: python, c, imap, restart

is there a way to restart another script in another shell?
i have script that sometimes stuck waiting to read email from gmail and imap. from another script i would like to restart the main one but without stopping the execution of the second 
i have tried:

```
os.system("C:\Users\light\Documents\Python\BOTBOL\Gmail\V1\send.py")
process = subprocess.Popen(["python", "C:\Users\light\Documents\Python\BOTBOL\Gmail\V1\send.py"])
```

but both run the main in the second's shell
EDIT:
sorry, for shell i mean terminal window

Comment: What do you mean by *in another shell*??? I know what processes and threads are, I know what a shell is, and also what a terminal window is, but I cannot understand what means *start another script in another shell*...

Comment: Terminal window, sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After your last comment and as the syntax show that you are using Windows, I assume that you want to launch a Python script in another console. The magic word here is `START` if you want that the launching execute in parallel with the new one, or `START /W` if you want to wait for the end of the subprocess.

In your case, you could use:

```
subprocess.call(["cmd.exe", "/c", "START", "C:\Path\To\PYTHON.EXE",
    "C:\Users\light\Documents\Python\BOTBOL\Gmail\V1\send.py"])
```

Answer (score 0):

Subprocess has an option called shell which is what you want. Os calls are blocking which means that only after the command is completed will the interpreter move to the next line. On the other hand subprocess popens are non blocking, however both these commands will spawn off child process from the process running this code. If you want to run in shell and get access shell features to execute this , try the shell = True in subprocess.

Comment: subprocess.Popen(["C:\Users\light\Documents\Python\BOTBOL\Gmail\V1\send.py"], shell = True)

Comment: still in the same shell

Comment: ill try doing it in 1 with threading.Thread(target=something).start()
threading.Thread(target=my_thing).start()

Comment: Have updated my answer - the separate shell part was vague , what i meant was you will be directly working with the shell. Also note that shell = True is a little dangerous - https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments A

Answer (score 0):

I could try and explain everything you need but I think this video will do it better: [Youtube Video about multithreading](https://youtu.be/PJ4t2U15ACo)

This will allow you to run 2 things f.e. 
Have 1 run on checkin email and the other one on inputs so it wont stop at those moments and making multiple 'shelves' possible, as they are parallel.

If you really want to have a different window for this, i am sorry and I can not help.

Hope this was were you were looking for.

Comment: i have tried, (probably not enough), but seems that it still wait the first thread to finish before starting the second (maybe im wrong)

Comment: It should be using 2 threads, but youll have 1 main and another in a def.